# Android 'ContactPhoneMailPicker' API?

Tags: android, android-activity, contacts, picker

When I use the native 'Messages' application in Android 2.2, it offers the choice of using 'ContactPhoneMailPicker' to select recipients.'ContactPhoneMailPicker' appears to be an Activity in the native 'People' application.

'ContactPhoneMailPicker' has exactly the functionality I need in an application I'm developing, but I can't find any information on it anywhere I've looked.

Question: Can I launch 'ContactPhoneMailPicker' as an explicit Intent? If so, where's the documentation?

Thanks.